# I need to echo ten lines to a text document using a batch file with echo off. The file gets saved, but each line says ECHO is off. my batch file is-

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off  
color a    
:ini  
set /p  1= %random%    
set /p  2= %random%   
set /p  3=  %random%  
set /p  4=  %random%  
set /p  5=  %random%  
set /p  6=  %random%  
set /p  7=  %random%  
set /p  8=  %random%  
set /p  9=  %random%  
set /p  10=  %random%
```

setting random numbers

```
(  

echo %1%  
echo %2%  
echo %3%  
echo %4%  
echo %5%  
echo %6%  
echo %7%  
echo %8%  
echo %9%  
echo %10%  
)>file.txt
```

trying to echo them to a file
My complication is that echo is off.
I need it to be off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables should not be named just a number. Per dbenham's comment below:

> %1% is interpreted as %1 (the first script argument) which happens to
>   be undefined in this case, followed by a lone % which is simply
>   consumed. Generally, you should not define a variable with a name
>   beginning with a number. But you can access such variables if you use
>   delayed expansion - %1% does not work, but !1! does work.

So in your case the parser encounters an invalid variable (e.g. `%1%`) so it only processes the `ECHO` command which simply outputs if ECHO is on or off.

Aside from that your script seems a bit off as you are attempting to prompt for 10 values using a random number as the prompt text.

If you just need to output 10 random numbers, you can do it "gracefully" using a `FOR` loop:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET FileName=file.txt
SET NumberOfValues=10

REM Remove existing file if it exists.
IF EXIST "%FileName%" DEL "%FileName%"

FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%NumberOfValues%) DO ECHO !RANDOM!>>file.txt

ENDLOCAL
```

Alternately, a more sucinct approach would be this one liner which you can run straight in the Windows command prompt (no batch file needed):

```
CMD /V:ON /C FOR /L %A IN (1,1,10) DO @ECHO !RANDOM!>file.txt
```

Comment: 1 is not an invalid variable, but `%1%` is interpreted as `%1` (the first script argument) which happens to be undefined in this case, followed by a lone `%` which is simply consumed. Generally, you should not define a variable with a name beginning with a number. But you can access such variables if you use delayed expansion - `%1%` does not work, but `!1!` does work.

Comment: @dbenham - I did not know that. I thought `%#%` was always invalid. Thanks for the info and I'll update the posted answer with this.

Comment: what if i need to echo something to fed in by the user?

Comment: @magnus167 - You would then use `SET /P VarName=Prompt:`. In your script above, it didn't make much sense in the context. Can you specify what you need to prompt the user for?

Comment: @jasonfaulkner - what i want to ask for their name, age etc then echo it to a txt file?

Comment: @magnus167 - You would do: `SET /P Age=Enter Your Age:` to get the value and then `ECHO %Age%>outfile.txt` to print it to a file. This is really a separate question as it is not related to what this post is about, so if you need further help then play around with it a bit and post any more questions.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner - what if i need to echo two different line?

Comment: @magnus167 - This is would be a separate question to post. If my response above solved the problem you originally posted about, please mark it as the answer to note that the question has been resolved. Cheers.